# How to get HTML element Angular using @ViewChild

Tags: angular, angular8

There is component with HTML:

```
<div class="filter" #filterContainer>
```

Inside another component I listen body scroll and try to apply scrollTop to element `#filterContainer`:

```
 export class SkeletonComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit, OnChanges {
      isSideBarOpen;

      @ViewChild("filterContainer", {
        read: ViewContainerRef,
        static: false
      })
      el: ElementRef;

      @HostListener("window:scroll", ["$event"])
      public scroll($event): void {
        let scrolled = $event.target.scrollingElement.scrollTop;
        console.log(this.el);
      }
    }
```

But when event fired I get `console.log(this.el);` is undefined, why I can not get access to element `#filterContainer`?

Comment: When you say "somewhere in Angular apps", do you mean it's in some child component?

Comment: Yes, it is child component

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The viewChild is only visible from the component you has the template reference variable. (and must be read:ElementRef, not read:ViewContainerRef

if your component has a parent, from this parent you need access to the component and then acces to the ViewChildren. And yes, you access to the children using a ViewChild from parent (or with a template reference)

e.g. our children

```
@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: `<h1 #filterContainer>Hello {{name}}!</h1>`,
  styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }`]
})
export class HelloComponent  {
  @Input() name: string;
  @ViewChild('filterContainer',{static:false}) filterComponent
}
```

Our parent

```
<hello #hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>
<button (click)="log(hello.filterComponent)">button</button>
<button (click)="log2()">button</button>

export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
  @ViewChild(HelloComponent,{static:false}) hello
  //or
  //@ViewChild('hello',{static:false,read:HelloComponent}) hello

  log(element)
  {
    console.log(element.nativeElement.innerHTML)
  }
  log2()
  {
    console.log(this.hello.filterComponent)
  }
}
```

Comment: Is this the right way to access ViewChild of child component inside the parent component?